# laravel Ubuntu 16.04 LAMP css and js files error 403

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.6

I am trying to get my Laravel application online om a Linux Ubuntu LAMP host.

I followed alot of tutorials to make it work.

I am the that point where the public html is loaded but the css and js are getting permission denied.

my .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

in filezilla i gave the directory's all the rights but that doesnt solve it.

I even create a fresh application on the server but that gave the same problem

Does someone know what could be wrong?

Comment: How do you include your assets?

Comment: ```<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>``` ```<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">```
like that @Robert, but if i go to the file it self www.example.com/css/app.js it also says access denied